# How to mock DbUpdateConcurrencyException

Tags: entity-framework-core, moq

I'm trying to mock function in my service to throw a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`. My code only needs to check for an exception of type `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` and doesn't need to read the exception message or list of entries that the constructor asks for.

I want to set up the `Mock` by calling a parameter-less constructor for `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`, but that doesn't exist in EFCore.

```
var mockService = new Mock<IMyService>();
mockService.Setup(service => service.UpdateFooAsync(It.IsNotNull<Data.Foo>())).Throws(new DbUpdateConcurrencyException());
```

I've tried calling `new DbUpdateConcurrencyException()` with some parameters, but there's some checks that happen on the parameters that prevents me from doing this with null/empty data.

`new DbUpdateConcurrencyException(null, null)` gives:

```
Message: System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: entries
```

`new DbUpdateConcurrencyException("", new List<IUpdateEntry>())` gives:

```
Message: System.ArgumentException : The collection argument 'entries' must contain at least one element.
```

Is there a way in Moq that I can mock the `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` without having to go through the checks that the constructor has?

Comment: Why do you think parameterless ctor doesn't exist `https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/master/src/EFCore/DbUpdateConcurrencyException.cs`?

Comment: The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbupdateconcurrencyexception?view=efcore-2.1) only show the two parameter constructor. Visual Studio also complains when I try to call `new DbUpdateConcurrencyException()` saying `There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'message' of 'DbUpdateConcurrencyException.DbUpdateConcurrencyException(string, IReadOnlyList<IUpdateEntry>)'`

Comment: Hm... :/. Could you try to pass then `string, new List<IUpdateEntry>{ Mock.Of<IUpdateEntry>()}`? They should not be null...

Comment: `String.Empty, new List<IUpdateEntry> { Mock.Of<IUpdateEntry>() }` works perfectly! If you post it as an answer I'll accept. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on docs you have shared in comments you should use ctor with two parameters. The trick is to provide not null `string` and not empty `List<IUpdateEntry>`, `moq` could help you with that, e.g.

```
new DbUpdateConcurrencyException(string.Empty, new List<IUpdateEntry>{Mock.Of<IUpdateEntry>()});
```